# On click function not working with bootsrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

Here is my on click function

```js
$(".addPizza").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello")
  let userId = $("#userId").attr("data-id");
  let pizzaRecipe = $('#pizza-recipe').val().trim();
  let ingredients = JSON.stringify(obj);
  let title = $("#pizza-title").val().trim();

  let newPizza = {
    userid: userId,
    recipe: pizzaRecipe,
    ingredients: ingredients,
    totalCal: calTotal,
    title: title
  };
  $.ajax('/api/pizza', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: newPizza
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Created new pizza recipe');
    location.reload();
  });
  $.ajax('/', newPizza).then(() => {
    console.log('Created new pizza recipe');
    // location.reload();
  });
});
```

and here is my html modal

```html
<button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Add a recipe</button>
<!-- end of button -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Recipe</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>

          <form class="recipe-form" action="/pizza" method="POST">
            <a id="userId" data-id=<%=user.id %></a>



            <input type="text" id="pizza-title" name="pizza-title" placeholder="title"><br>
            <input type="text" id="pizza-recipe" name="pizza-recipe" placeholder="recipe"><br>

            <label for="vegy1">Cucumber</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy1" data-name="cucumber" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy2">Tomato</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy2" data-name="tomato" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy3">Pineapple</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy3" data-name="pineapple" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy4">Avocado</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy4" data-name="avocado" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

            <label for="vegy5">Eggplant</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy5" data-name="eggplant" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy6">Olive</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy6" data-name="olive" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy7">Onion</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy7" data-name="onion" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy8">Mushroom</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy8" data-name="mushroom" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

            <label for="vegy9">Garlic</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy9" data-name="garlic" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy10">Spinach</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy10" data-name="spinach" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy11">Cilantro</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy11" data-name="cilantro" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy12">Chicken</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy12" data-name="chicken" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

            <label for="vegy13">Anchovy</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy13" data-name="anchovy" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy14">Bacon</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy14" data-name="bacon" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy15">Sausage</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy15" data-name="sausage" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy16">Beef</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy16" data-name="beef" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

            <label for="vegy17">Ham</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy17" data-name="ham" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy18">Pepperoni</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy18" data-name="pepperoni" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy19">Salami</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy19" data-name="salami" min="0" max="3" value="0">

            <label for="vegy20">Banana</label>
            <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy20" data-name="banana" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

            <p id="totalCal"></p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addPizza">Add Recipe</button>
            </div>

          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
let mysql = require("mysql");

let connection;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) 
    // DB is JawsDB on Heroku
    connection = mysql.createConnection(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
else 
    // DB is local on localhost
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        port: 3306,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'pass',
        database: 'pizza_recipe_db'
    });

// Establish connection to MySQL
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`error connecting MySQL: ${err.stack} \n`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Connected to MySQL as id ${connection.threadId} \n`);
});

// Export connection
module.exports = connection;
```

It is also giving me this error when I click on the add recipe button
GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSTPOST    http://localhost:3000/api/pizza net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

POST http://localhost:3000/api/pizza net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I was told I should use "event delegation" I am not sure how to do that though.

Thanks for your help. If you need any more code just let me know. thank you!

Comment: @SudhirSapkal should I try loading it in a different browser?

Comment: Shall I know your scritp loading structure? like jquery,bootstrap,etc...

Comment: @mariappank im using jquery, and bootstrap

Comment: @SudhirSapkal so update... I got the errors to go away by switching my browser to firefox. I have also got the recipe to be logged in my console just not into my database

Comment: @Bayli Sade : So that's because the server from where you are calling API is not in running state , localhost:3000/api/pizza , Try to restart localhost:3000 server, You will get the response stored in DB

Comment: @SudhirSapkal still no response in my DB.

Comment: @SudhirSapkal no error in my browser. but in terminal this is the error it gives and then shuts the server down -  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors. It does log my recipe in terminal though

Comment: @SudhirSapkal added the server code into the question up top ^^

Comment: @BayliSade I think your loading jquery file after https://stacksnippets.net/js file that's why it's throw error $ not defined. Please load jquery before this and let check

Comment: @SudhirSapkal my port im using is localhost:3000

Comment: @SudhirSapkal No, the Database server port is 3306

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not closed anchor tag properly in HTML and that's why the user id is not getting right. 
Check Following line

```
<a id="userId" data-id=<%=user.id %></a>
```

It should be

```
<a id="userId" data-id=<%=user.id %>></a>
```

As it was not closed correctly, JS was sending `userid = 3 </a` and at Mysql your column is user_id is not a text, It is unsigned integer. That's why your insertion code was failing to insert the Text value into integer column and throwing sql exception and server operation was exited. That's why you have got a error

```
http://localhost:3000/          net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSTPOST 
http://localhost:3000/api/pizza net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

As the server is exited and it is not running.

Change the anchor tag given above and your code will be working perfectly.